# Who should be responsible to write test cases?

Tags: testing, tdd

Should tests in some project be written by the actual person that does the coding (usually senior in our team) or it can be done by junior coders with less experience?

Comment: What type of tests?

Comment: @MichaelT Unit testing, tests as part of the code

Comment: Do "junior coders" don't do any "actual" coding in your team? What are they doing then?

Comment: I disagree this is a duplicate of the TDD question. That question is specifically about TDD, this one is more general. I think both questions have merit. The acid test, for me, is that I wouldn't move my own answer to the other question because it doesn't apply there.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann They do but simpler things. Data access layer is usually done by senior.

Comment: Unless I miss something, reopen justification doesn't make sense to me.  **1.** "[That question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/35610/31260) is specifically about TDD, this one is..." surprise! it is explicitly and unambigously tagged [tag:tdd] [from the very beginning!](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/revisions/206673/1 "first revision"). Those who believe this question isn't about TDD, didn't even bother to clean up that tag (along with appropriate explanation) - that's not how clearing the difference between dupes is expected to work...

Comment: ... **2.** "The acid test..." is not acid anymore. The current [MSO guidance](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/166707/165773) dropped the ancient requirement of dupes to be "exact / mergeable", so the fact that some answers can't be moved between dupes is totally irrelevant here, as question merges and moving the answers aren't enforced anymore...

Comment: ...And all this massive rework of duplicates system has been done with the purpose to *make it easier for site readers to find answers relevant / useful to question asked*! Now, **why** do we deprive site visitors from that here, simply escapes my mind

Comment: Yes, this has the tag tdd, but tdd appears nowhere in the question or title. So, while the question can be applied to tdd, it isn't exclusive to it. I think the question appeals to a broader audience. If the actual question being asked is edited to explicitly mention then I can agree on it being a duplicate.

Comment: @BryanOakley it is a bit to late to bend it to "wider": there are already answers posted (and fairly good ones) that [rely on the question being asked in the context of TDD](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/206686/31260 "'Ideally, in test driven design...'")

Comment: ...to avoid misunderstanding, I don't insist that it's a dupe yet (need some time to study both questions to make up my mind on that), merely point that arguments in favor of reopening are questionable

Comment: @gnat: isn't also true that there are answers that rely on the question _not_ being strictly about TDD, including the accepted answer?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is no single answer to this question. Obviously, if you're a business with a single developer then the developer should write the tests. If you're an organization of a thousand developers, the answer will be different.

Assuming a "normal" team with a few developers and possibly a few people dedicated to testing, it goes something like this:

1. developers write unit tests
2. developers and/or QA write integration tests
3. QA writes acceptance tests

In the scrum model, there is no distinction between "developer" and "QA". The team as a whole is responsible for the quality of the software, and the team decides on a case-by-case basis who should be doing the testing.

Many smart people think developers should write all their tests. I've worked in organizations like that, and we always delivered exceptionally high quality software. In those companies, not only *should* senior devs write tests, they *must*.

Other very smart people believe that developers should *not* test their own code because they have blinders on. "I don't need to test X, my changes couldn't possibly have affected it". To combat that you should always have someone else write the tests. I've worked in those types of organizations, and there, too, we also delivered  high quality code.

The bottom line is that if you're a developer, *you* are ultimately responsible for the quality of the code you produce. That means you should be writing tests -- regardless of organizational structure -- and if you have other team members, then you should work with them to make sure the code is properly tested.

In practical terms, the only people who can answer this for you is you and your team. It's perfectly reasonable for senior level programmers to write tests (and if they are good programmers, you won't ever have to ask them to do it because that's just part of the job). It's also perfectly reasonable for junior people to write tests -- this is a good way for them to learn the software.

In either case, there is no *should*. You should do whatever allows your team to create software with an appropriate level of quality.

Comment: I always advocated the idea that every developer should test code - just not their own. In any case, its never an excuse for some developers to pass off the boring testing work to some poor schmuck.

Comment: If a senior developer write non testable code and give those code to junior developer then `this is a good way for them to learn the software` is not valid statement. R8?

Comment: @SaifulAzad: If any developer gives another developer *non-testable* code, that's not good for anything. If a senior developer is giving a junior developer *untested* code, then they aren't a very good senior developer. I don't think I've ever met a decent senior-level developer who didn't test their code at least a little.

Comment: For example, I am labeled as senior developer and manager instructs me to code & little functional test just & pass to junior developer to write extensive unit test. As my manager believes writing test by junior developer is more cost effective than me. My question to you that if I write a function which is difficult to unit test (calling rest API in function, long function) and pass that to junior developer is that good way to work? I have seen many time I have to rewrite the whole function just to support unit test. Does passing code to junior developers to test aligned TDD(Test driven dev)?

Answer (score 10):

Edit: I read the title as unit tests:

I have heard this idea before, and IMHO I think it is a terrible idea to force unit testing solely on junior developers.

You would be creating an unnecessary division in your team.

Developers should write unit tests for their own code. Both the code and unit tests will then in the future be updated by other developers as features changes and bugs are discovered depending on resource availability.

Not trusting juniors with real features is not the best way to manage projects. Start them on smaller or easier features, let them unit test them, and they can work their way up to bigger, harder features.

Comment: I think it is an anti-pattern to have the concept of a 'junior developer'.   Every team member has stronger and weaker areas, it's the job of the team leader to load balance the work.  If the leader decrees that unit testing is something left to 'junior' then nobody will take testing seriously.  That's a bad thing IMHO.

Comment: @JimInTexas I agree!

Answer (score 5):

Ideally, in test driven design, the test is written before a single line of code is written.  Someone writes the failing test, someone writes the code (that passes).

In this model, it doesn't matter too much who writes the test (or who does the code).  What *is* required is that the test accurately describes the functionality to be written before writing code.  If this understanding of the requirements requires a senior programmer, then that is who writes it.

However, once the test is written, if it was well written, *anyone* should be able to write the code for it that passes the test.  If anything, this points to that seniors should be writing the all tests and then delegating out the coding of the guts of the code to other people who can do it.

After the fact unit testing is.. less than ideal.  Unfortunately, when this happens this is often left to the juniors to "get the required coverage."  Such endeavors are often difficult because they are tedious and don't fully test the code in question (leaving bugs that get scapegoated on the person who wrote the test for not catching it).

It is great having junior programmers gain experience with the code base.  Forcing them to write after the fact unit testing isn't the way to do it.